# Getting elements on same level as checked input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Mornin' StackOverflow.

I am having some neurological problems trying to find sibling columns of a checkbox.

Table structure is (roughly) as follows:

```
<tr>
    <td><input CHECKED type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td data-context="key 1">Sibling 1</td>
    <td data-context="key 2">Sibling 2</td>
    <td data-context="key 3">Sibling 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td data-context="key 4">Sibling 1</td>
    <td data-context="key 5">Sibling 2</td>
    <td data-context="key 6">Sibling 3</td>
</tr>
```

Now, what I have to do, is get all the sibling elements of the checked checkbox (all the elements within the  which checkbox has been checked). I've tried using Jquery's .siblings() and .each() on that, however it turns up with nothing.

I'm obviously missing something important.

Comment: Just post your tried jQuery

Comment: your checkbox is a child element of the `td` so you need to get the siblings of its parent td.  Something like `$(this).parent('td').siblings('td')` and possibly a chained `.find('input')` or something, if "Sibling X" really represents other input elements and you're going for those instead of the actual sibling `td`'s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to do with the data but you can use jquery `is.(":checked")` and then find the `.parent().siblings()` of the input to get the info (input is a child so you need to back out to the parent level then you can look at the siblings)

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/y8Q4a/)

Answer (score 0):

As the others have stated, I wasn't thinking straight.

I needed to get the parent of the , and then it's siblings. Thanks for the swift answers, upvotes and accepts for all.